# Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed laravel Queue

Tags: laravel-5, goutte

I am scraping a site a get some of the data and it's a time taking job so I googled and found that Queue is good for this process I am stucked in this error

```
Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed
```

My code:

```
class SiteScraper extends Job implements ShouldQueue
{
    use InteractsWithQueue, SerializesModels;

    protected $client;
    protected $crawler;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {

        $this->client = new Client();
        $this->crawler = $this->client->request('GET', 'example.com/login/');
        $form = $this->crawler->selectButton('Log In')->form();
        $this->crawler = $this->client->submit($form, array('email' => 'useremail', 'pass' => 'pass'));
        $this->crawler->filter('.flash-error')->each(function ($node) {
            print $node->text() . "\n";
        });
    }
 public function handle()
{

    $crawler = $this->client->request('GET', $url_to_traverse);
    $status_code = $this->client->getResponse()->getStatus();

        if($status_code == 200){
            $crawler->filter('.friendBrowserNameTitle > a')->each(function ($node) {
                $names = $node->text() . '<br>';
                $profileurl = $node->attr('href') . '<br>';
                echo "Name : " . $names . "  Profile Link : " . $profileurl;

            });
        }
        else{
            echo $status_code;
        }

    }
}
```

Any help where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Only Eloquent models will be gracefully serialized and unserialized when the job is processing ([Source](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queues#writing-job-classes))

So I guess that in your case, you have to write your current construct code into **handle()** method

```
class SiteScraper extends Job implements ShouldQueue
{
    use InteractsWithQueue, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(){ }

    public function handle()
    {

        $client = new Client();
        $crawler = $client->request('GET', 'example.com/login/');
        $form = $crawler->selectButton('Log In')->form();
        $crawler = $client->submit($form, array('email' => 'useremail', 'pass' => 'pass'));
        $crawler->filter('.flash-error')->each(function ($node) {
            print $node->text() . "\n";
        });

        $crawler = $client->request('GET', $url_to_traverse);
        $status_code = $client->getResponse()->getStatus();

        if($status_code == 200){
            $crawler->filter('.friendBrowserNameTitle > a')->each(function ($node) {
                $names = $node->text() . '<br>';
                $profileurl = $node->attr('href') . '<br>';
                echo "Name : " . $names . "  Profile Link : " . $profileurl;

            });
        }
        else{
            echo $status_code;
        }

    }
}
```